# Storing TTreeView inside SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, delphi, tadoquery

Am trying to store my `TTreeView` inside SQL Server database table by using the next procedure:

```
procedure Save;
var
  BlobField :TBlobField;
  Query:TADOQuery;
  Stream:TStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Query := TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  Query.SQL.Add('Select * From MyTable') ;
  Query.Active := True;
  Query.First;
  Query.Edit;
  BlobField := Query.FieldByName('MyTableField') as TBlobField;
  Stream := Query.CreateBlobStream(BlobField, bmWrite);
  TreeView1.SaveToStream(Stream);
  Query.Refresh;
  Query.Free;
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

But every time I am getting the error: `DataSet is not in edit or insert mode`.

I'm using Delphi 10.1, Win 10, SQL server 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Query.Refresh;` to `Query.Post;`

Also, you need to `Free` the blob stream to finalize writing to the blob field before you then `Post` to commit the new data into the DB.

Also, you are leaking an unused `TMemoryStream` object.

Try this:

```pascal
procedure Save;
var
  BlobField: TField;
  Query: TADOQuery;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Query := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    Query.SQL.Text := 'Select TOP(1) * From MyTable';
    Query.Open;
    try
      Query.First;
      Query.Edit;
      try
        BlobField := Query.FieldByName('MyTableField');
        Stream := Query.CreateBlobStream(BlobField, bmWrite);
        try
          TreeView1.SaveToStream(Stream);
        finally
          Stream.Free;
        end;
        Query.Post;
      except
        Query.Cancel;
        raise;
      end;
    finally
      Query.Close;
    end;
  finally
    Query.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The line : BlobField := Query.FieldByName('MyTableField'); I think that it must be : Query.FieldByName('MyTableField') as TBlobField;  Regards .

Comment: @Issam [`CreateBlobStream()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.CreateBlobStream) takes in a `TField` as a parameter, not a `TBlobField` (yes, the `TField` does need to point at a valid `TBlobField` object, though). And [`FieldByName()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FieldByName) returns a `TField`. So the typecast is redundant and can be omitted.